# How do i make my chrome extension remember the toggle switch or other actions?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

my chrome extension does not remember the toggle switch. I am trying to make an extension that blocks the youtube feed and comment when the toggle switch is on. I tried to do it for comment section but it is not working.

```js
if(document.getElementById("input1").checked == true){
  document.getElementByClassName("ytd-comments").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Rounded switch -->
    <div>
    <label class="switch">
    <input id="input0" type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
    <p class="ch-text">yotube feed<p>
      </div>
    <!-- switch for the comments -->
    <div>
    <label class="switch">
    <input id= "input1" type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
    <p class="ch-text">comment section<p>
      </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="background.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

my manifest json:

```
  {
  "name": "Youtube feed Blocker",
  "description": "Removing the feed and comments from the youtube to stop wasting time",
  "icons": {"128": "icon.png"},
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
      "tabs", "http://*.youtube.com/*", "https://*.youtube.com/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Removed the recommended videos sections",
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "persistent": true
  },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "css": ["style.css"],
        "matches": ["*://www.youtube.com/", "*://www.youtube.com/watch*", "*://www.youtube.com/*", "*://www.youtube.com/user*"],
        "all_frames": true,
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }],

  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [storage.sync API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-sync), as explained here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options

Although there are other methods, using the sync API will remember user's settings across devices.